# Forced Redirect on a server migration

Tags: redirect, migration

I have backedup and installed my site on a new server underneath the new domain of

```
http://old.example.com
```

After the DB and file transfer I logged in and immediately got a 500 error.  I then overwrote the `.htaccess` file to the default and renamed the plugin folder to `plugins-rename` and then tested again.

Now the site resolves, but then automatically redirects the browser to

```
https://example.com
```

I also forced the site to exist under it's new old.example.com within the WP-config file using the following commands

```
define('WP_HOME','http://old.example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://old.example.com');
```

Any ideas where this redirection might exist as it can't be contained within a plugin so must be somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a clean and sure way that I follow when I migrate a WordPress to a new domain (or subdomain):

1. Go and download [Interconnect IT's Database Search & Replace Script here](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/archive/master.zip)
2. Unzip the file and drop the folder where your WordPress is installed (the root) and rename the folder to **`replace`** ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Ga5.png))
3. Navigate to the new folder you created in your browser (ex: `http://old.example.com/replace`) and [you will see the search/replace tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbED1.png)
4. In the "*search for…*" and "*replace with…*" fields:

   - **Replace**: `https://example.com` (old domain)
   - **With**: `http://old.example.com` (new domain)

You can click the *dry run* button under *actions* to see what it will be replacing before you execute the script. Once you're done be sure to remove the `/replace/` folder.

Comment: I performed all the actions you mentioned but I am still being redirected.  Does the script only search the DB or does it also search the files? I did have a few errors I have a feeling that there is a hardcoded `The table "wp_login_redirects" has no primary key. Changes will have to be made manually.` was one of the errors I got which might mean the issue resides in this area?  Any other ideas of how to spot where a redirect might be being issues when i visit the site?